# parse: match in the middle part of a string

Tags: python, string, parsing, partial

I am using the [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) package to extract some information from strings. I have a pattern like:

```
pattern = compile("hello {}")
s = "I am Jack, hello Mike, hello Tom! nice to meet you."
pattern.parse(s)
```

I want to extract '`Mike`', '`Tom`' out of s, no matter what's before and after the matched patterns in the string. How should I modify my pattern?

Comment: Is `parse` really needed here? For this case, the very common `re` library is a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) like so:

```
import re
s = "I am Jack, hello Mike, hello Tom! nice to meet you."
names = re.findall(r'[Hh]ello\s+(\w+)', s)
print(names)
# ['Mike', 'Tom']
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for the case. Thanks. Unfortunately I am really a dumb of re, and have a bunch of more patterns to find in my data. So if parse could work, it's preferred.